# Do Firestore transactions use backoff logic (linear or exponential) when retrying?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firestore document with an array of objects that I sometimes write to more than once per second. With Firebase suggesting a max write rate of 1/second, this can be problematic, in theory.

So far, transactions seem to mostly help me avoid high rate document write failures, so I haven't bothered to restructure it into a subcollection.  From what I can tell though, Firestore transactions don't do any sort of linear or exponential backoff between retries.  Has anyone had success with adding a `sleep` call between transaction attempts to emulate this kind of behavior?  It seems odd that Firebase wouldn't design their transactions with an option to enable backoff behavior.

Comment: From what I can tell Firestore queues the writes if the number of reasonable yet there are too many for any given DB at that moment in time. I would reconsider how you're writing to Firestore if you think you'll be hitting it that often. If it's for counting, consider Firestore Extensions which can handle up to 10,000 writes/second.

Comment: Thanks for the Firestore Extension recommendation.  It's the first I've heard of it.  However, this isn't really a counting problem.  I have an array of user maps on the document, where each user has a "status" field.  On average, I expect the document to contain no more than ~8 users.  The users are updating their status within a roughly 1 minute timeframe, so there's a good chance that concurrent user status updates on the document can happen within a single second.

Comment: I think in that case they'll just get queued up and done sequentially. The 1/second is not a hard limit. Even if all 8 were in one second that seems reasonable to queue up.

Answer (score -1):

The Firebase documentation states that you should not update a single document more than once per second because your application will experience "contention, including higher latency, timeouts, and other errors" [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of what the Firebase documentation states with regard to single document write rates.  I just wish they would elaborate on this side note: "Write rates to a single document can sometimes exceed the one per second limit so load tests might not show this problem."  Do transactions actually help bump the 1/second number up?  What else can be done to increase the chance of success when a single document is updated more than once/second?

Comment: Since Node.js Firestore transactions don't delay backoff at the moment, the transactions probably _worsen_ the problem in some respects as it will retry the same transaction multiple times in a row immediately (5 times by default).

You could queue the writes in the event that too many came in at once or in the case that a write failed. The following question has some examples of introducing delayed writes and queues:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339969/error-10-aborted-too-much-contention-on-these-documents-please-try-again

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and should be a comment.