# How to avoid nesting promises with firebase transaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In an onDelete trigger I'm running a transaction to update some object. I now need to do some cleanup and delete some other objects before running that transaction. After adding the cleanup code I'm getting a warning about nesting promises which I don't know how to get rid of. Here is a snippet:

```
exports.onDeleteAccount = functions.firestore
.document('accounts/{accountID}')
.onDelete((account, context) => {
  // First do the cleanup and delete addresses of the account
  const query = admin.firestore().collection('account_addresses').where('accountID', '==', account.id);
  return query.get().then(addresses => {
    var promises = [];
    addresses.forEach(address=>{
      promises.push(address.ref.delete());
    })
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }).then(()=> {
    // Then run the transaction to update the account_type object
    return runTransaction(transaction => {
      // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
      const acc_type = account.data().type;
      const accountTypeRef = admin.firestore().doc("account_types/"+acc_type);
      return transaction.get(accountTypeRef).then(accTypeDoc => {
        // Do some stuff and update an object called users
        transaction.update(accountTypeRef, {users: users});
        return;          
      })
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("AccountType delete transaction failed. Error: "+error);
  });
})
```

Comment: you can try to use `await`, but I'm not sure it's fully supported or not (I don't use firebase)

Comment: I think there is no problem at first glance.

Comment: @appleapple I get a warning on the transaction.get line to avoid nesting promises. If I remove the cleanup code (the query.get() call) then this warning go away...

Comment: @ shaimo I mean there is no problem using `await`, sorry for not being claer.

Comment: oh wait, does `runTransaction` returns Promise?

Comment: @appleapple yes, I think so

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the problem comes from the `Transaction` but from the `forEach` loop where you call `delete()`. You should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to return a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises (returned by `delete()`) passed to the `promises` array have been fulfilled, see below.

---

In addition, you do `runTransaction(transaction => {...})` but [`runTransaction`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#runTransaction) is a method of [`Firestore`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html). You should do `admin.firestore().runTransaction(...)`.

---

Therefore, the following should do the trick:

```
exports.onDeleteAccount = functions.firestore
    .document('accounts/{accountID}')
    .onDelete((account, context) => {
        // First do the cleanup and delete addresses of the account
        const query = admin.firestore().collection('account_addresses').where('accountID', '==', account.id);
        return query.get()
            .then(addresses => {
                const promises = [];
                addresses.forEach(address => {
                    promises.push(address.ref.delete());
                })
                return Promise.all(promises);
            }).then(() => {
                // Then run the transaction to update the account_type object
                return admin.firestore().runTransaction(transaction => {
                    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
                    const acc_type = account.data().type;
                    const accountTypeRef = admin.firestore().doc("account_types/" + acc_type);
                    return transaction.get(accountTypeRef).then(accTypeDoc => {
                        // Do some stuff and update an object called users
                        transaction.update(accountTypeRef, { users: users }); 
                    })
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("AccountType delete transaction failed. Error: " + error);
            });
    })
```

Comment: You are right about the need for Promise.all (btw, I think promises should be var, not const) and I changed my code accordingly (will update here in a sec). But still it doesn't remove the promise nesting warning on the line with "transaction.get"

Comment: Ok, let me have a look.

Comment: BTW, FYI, the values inside the const array can be change, it can add new items to const arrays but it cannot reference to a new array.

Comment: You do `runTransaction(transaction => {})` but `runTransaction` is a method of [Firestore](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html). You should do `admin.firestore().runTransaction(...)`.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I'm actually using my own runTransaction and didn't include it in the snippet. However, I tried it also with "admin.firestore().runTransaction" instead and the warning is still there on "transaction.get".

Comment: Thanks for your help @renaud-tarnec. I guess I'll just have to ignore this annoying warning then...;-)

Comment: Yes, the code looks OK, IMHO. I think it is probably a TSLint warning that you can ignore.

Comment: @shaimo BTW, did you solve your problem from this other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710330/unreliable-google-firebase-transactions

Comment: Yes, I pointed there to this answer that I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339969/error-10-aborted-too-much-contention-on-these-documents-please-try-again