# How to fix "too much contention" on onCreate triggered by batch writes

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have school object with classrooms and students.  Students are each family's sub-collection.  When creating a school, I write several hundred families in several write batches.

In creating each student, I want to do a few things:

- update a string in the student's family containing student first names
- students contain a classroom id, and I wish to update the classroom with some data from the student
- the school keeps separate list of students for easy lookup, and I want to add the students there

That code looks like this...

```
exports.didCreateStudent = functions.firestore.document(studentPath).onCreate((snap, context) => {
  return Promise.all([
    updateFamilyNames(snap.ref.parent.parent),
    updateClassroomStudent(snap, null, snap.data().classroom),
    updateStudentCollection(null, snap)
  ])
})
```

Each of those functions performs a transaction.  The first gets the student's family and writes kids names, the second does something like the same on the student's classroom, and so on.  (I do these on triggers to get the behavior on updates and deletes, also).

For example, the salient part of the `updateClassroomStudent` looks like this...

```
  return transaction.get(classroomDocRef).then(snapshot => {
    const student = Object.assign({}, _.pick(studentSnapshot.data(), 'firstName', 'lastName', 'grade'), { ref: studentSnapshot.ref })
    const addition = { students: { [studentSnapshot.id]: student } }
    return transaction.set(snapshot.ref, addition, { merge: true })
  })
```

This works fine for small schools (10s of families, with about 2 students apiece), but on larger schools (100s of families), I begin to see `Error: 10 ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again.`

I can avoid the errors by skipping both `updateClassroomStudent` and `updateStudentCollection`, but not if I allow either one (or both) to run.

Will it help to not use transactions? When a few hundred docs are created with a write batch (like the student's families), will the `onCreate` triggers run sequentially? If so, maybe I can skip the transaction and save some overhead, maybe just pausing between batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions triggers do not have a guaranteed execution order, nor are they necessarily executed in serial.  If your code kicks off hundreds of events that trigger a function, that function could very well run hundreds in parallel.  That is creation a lot of contention for the document at `snapshot.ref`.

I suggest also reading this, which covers the same error, with a different use case: [Error: 10 ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52339969/807126)

By "contention", I mean that there are lots of concurrent access to a document via a transaction.  The transaction handler is being retried too many time due to all of the writes.  This behavior is stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions):

> In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

Later, [it says the transaction can fail when](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transaction_failure):

> The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again. The transaction is retried a finite number of times.

Without seeing all your code, it's hard to recommend a course of action, but I think the key will be to try to change the way your scheme works by applying all of the updates to the document in a single transaction rather than allowing lots of transactions to collide over many updates.

Another much more scalable option is to store the list of students as individual documents in a subcollection rather than as a list field in a single document.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you recommend the most up-voted answer on the thread you reference?  I read that before posting and was dissatisfied with the idea of tweaking retries and waits until it worked (brittle, I think).  To clarify, is it just docs -- not collections -- where the locks occur?

Comment: I only recommend that question as additional reading for your consideration. There is more than one way to solve many problems.

Comment: The documents where contention occurs most are "classrooms" where 30ish students at once could be trying to stuff in some reference info about themselves (that's the code I provided).  The only time this happens in volume is when all the families in a school are created at once. I know I could do this with a transaction per classroom, but I also want to handle a one-off student insert later on via the trigger.  I wish I could disable the triggers for a big write operation.  I cannot, right?

Comment: That's correct.  As I said in my last sentence, the scalable way to do this would be separate documents for each student.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'll accept this as good advice about execution order. I now understand the problem to be unrelated to the triggers and caused by a small code change. Fixing it leaves me confused about how to proceed.  I've detailed the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504553/batch-writing-in-firestore-can-i-write-children-before-parents and would be much obliged for your advice.