# Batch writing in firestore, can I write children before parents?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My app parses some JSON and creates data like this:

```
   School -- has several sub collections...
   |
   Classrooms -- about 25 docs
   |
   Staff -- about 30 docs
   |
   Families -- ~350 docs, each with sub collections...
      |
      Parents -- a few docs, usually 2
      |
      Students -- a few docs, usually 1 or 2
```

In all, there are about 1500 docs which I write in several batch sets using the following code (for creates, it uses only 'set'):

```
  // this.batchOps is a large array of:
  // [ { operation:'set', ref: firestore ref, data: { simple object }, ...]
  performBatchOps () {
    if (this.batchOps.length === 0) return Promise.resolve()
    const batchSize = 200 // I realize this may be as high as 500
    let batch = db.batch();
    this.batchOps.slice(0, batchSize).forEach(s => {
      if (s.operation === 'set') batch.set(s.ref, s.data)
      else if (s.operation === 'update') batch.update(s.ref, s.data)
      else if (s.operation === 'delete') batch.delete(s.ref)
    })
    return batch.commit().then(() => this.performBatchOps(this.batchOps.slice(batchSize)))
  }
```

I have two versions of this code. One reliably succeeds and one reliably fails. The only difference between the two versions is that the successful one creates the school (the parent of everything) *before* the batch, and the failing one creates the school *within* the batch...

```
// works
return schoolRef.set(schoolData).then(() => {
    this.batchOps = this.parseJSON(someJson)
    return this.performBatchOps()  // these batch ops don't contain a set for the school
}) 

// breaks
let batchOps = this.parseJSON(someJson) // the first batch op sets the school
return performBatchOps()
```

I think I understand that batch writes do not preserve order, and I thought I understood that a creation of a document like:  database/x/y/z/document, can precede the creation of the tree above it (that writing it implicitly writes its lineage).

The failure manifests in the logs as `Error: 10 ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again.`, [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461874/how-to-fix-too-much-contention-on-oncreate-triggered-by-batch-writes/61462451#61462451) (when I thought the problem was related to triggers that run on create).

I know I'll have to change the code to write the school doc first, but must I rearrange the child writes also (setup the whole tree outside of the batch and only write leaves in batch)?

I guess the contention error is related to contention on the school doc. Is there a place I can/could have discovered that in the logs?  It would have saved me tons of deploy-test-fix cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The order of operations in a batch does not matter at all, regardless of parent/child relationship.  Child documents can exist just fine without a parent document - they are completely unrelated to each other except by how you define their relation.

The error message is telling you that you're performing too many writes too quickly on a single document, probably that school doc as you mentioned.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions), the write limit for a single document is 1 per second.  You can exceed that in a short burst, but it can't be sustained.

Comment: That was my understanding, which would imply that the two approaches I try would behave the same, but one works and one fails.  ie it works when I write the top level parent by itself, then batch write everything else, but it fails when batch write everything including the top level parent.  I log the paths in the batches in the two approaches, and the paths being set are identical except for the presence of the top level.  Can you venture a guess about why?  (Including my test is wrong somehow).

Comment: Also, I think I could get to the bottom of this quickly if I knew which doc(s) was suffering from too much contention.  Is there  a way to learn this?

Comment: Reduce the size of your batch to 1.

Comment: Do you mean ~1500 batches of length 1?