# Firestore bulk delete documents results in GRPC StatusRuntimeException "ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents"

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We want to remove several documents based on a query. The resulting snapshots are removed in batches of 500. The code looks like this

```java
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutures;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.*;

...

long delete(List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> docs) {
    List<ApiFuture<List<WriteResult>>> results = new ArrayList<>();

    long count = 0;
    WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : docs) {
        count++;
        if (count % 500 == 0) {            // every 500 docs, commit batch and start a new one
            results.add(batch.commit());
            batch = db.batch();
        }
        batch.delete(doc.getReference());
    }
    results.add(batch.commit());           // commit final batch
    await(ApiFutures.allAsList(results));
    return count;
}
```

The `await` method near the end, just calls `ApiFuture<?>.get()` and wraps the exception in a RuntimeException.

Running this on a test setup deletes >700 documents without any issue. However, in an environment with live data, we get the following error

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AbortedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:533)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:90)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AbortedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again.
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
        at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1056)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:958)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:545)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:515)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again.
        at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

The documents I try to delete are written once and then never touched after that. The business requirement is to model an activity log that can be viewed by administrators. Technically, we run a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) with a `date < 6 months ago` restriction to get all the snapshots.

We use

- firebase-admin: 6.14.0
- google-cloud-firestore 1.34.0 (via firebase-admin)

Any ideas what I can do to resolve this problem or avoid this *ABORTED* status?

Comment: I suggest doing a web search for that error message ("ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again.") to learn about specific situations when it can occur.

Comment: @DougStevenson From what I found, the "contention" can be caused by other operations that modify the underlying data. See also [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#transactions_and_data_contention). However, in my case, the data has not been changed for 6 months: The data is written once and the query only include snapshots created more than 6 months ago.

Comment: If you are using Java, it usually reports errors with line numbers in the code files. Do you have anything more with this error?

Comment: @MrTech I have extended the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find this link with valuable information (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339969/error-10-aborted-too-much-contention-on-these-documents-please-try-again)

Comment: @MrTech Thank you for trying to help here. However, I do not understand how deleting documents that were written more than 6 months ago and haven't been touched since can result in "contention" problems.

Comment: I've found some best practices in the document (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices) to help guide you to resolve the contention issue you are having. Please take a look to see if they've been followed  in the design of your program.

Comment: @MrTech all applicable best practices have been followed. Any specific suggestions for the problem I have described?

Comment: If the data is not being accessed or used, the delete should succeed according to (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention) that you mentioned earlier. So as you are describing, if there is contention error with the data remaining untouched, you may consider using the link here (https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) to report a bug. I have been unable to find common issues reported by other issues recently. This will allow the correct team to begin an investigation.