# Firestore : Maintaining the count of a collection. Trigger function vs transaction

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have a collection called `persons` and another collection called `cities` with a field `population`. When a `Person` is created in a `City`, I would like to increment the  `population` field in the corresponding city.

I have two options.

1. Create a `onCreate` trigger function. Find the `city` document and increment using `FieldValue.increment(1)`.
2. Create an HTTPS callable cloud function to create the person. The cloud function executes a transaction in which the person is created and the population is incremented.

The first one is simpler and I am using it right now. But, I am wondering if there could be cases where the `onCreate` is not called due to some glitch...

I am thinking of moving to the second option. I am wondering if there are any disadvantages. Does HTTPS callable function cost more?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with the HTTPS callables would be that if something fails you would need to handle that on your client side. That would be (at least for me) a little bit to much logic for the client side.

What I can recommend you after almost 4 years experience with exactly that problem is a solution with a virtual `queue`. I had a long dicussion on that theme [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085147/5519300) and even with the Firebase ppl on the last in person Google IO and Firebase Summit.

Our problem was that there where those glitches and even if they happend sometimes the changes and transaction failed due to too much requests. After trying every offical recommendation like the `shard` counters etc. we ended up creating a virtual `queue` where each `onCreate` adds an entry to just a Firestore or RTD list/collection and another function that runs eaither by `crone` or another trigger (that doesn't matter). That cloud function handles each entry in the `queue` one by one and starts again for each of them to awoid timouts and memeroy limits. We made sure one handler/calculation is enought for a single function to handle it.

This method was the only bullet proof one that could handle thousands of new entries in a second without having an issue. The only downside is that it takes more time than an usual trigger because each entries is calculated one by one. If your calculations are smaller you could do them in batches (that is how we started to).

Comment: Do you think we still need this with `FieldValue.increment` in place?

Comment: FieldValue.increment doesn’t solve the issues that arise when updating a Firestore document "too" often. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document

Comment: I would not rely on `FieldValue.increment`. It is out of your control when it can fail. With the `queu` you need to ensure that only one increment is done at a time. That is the whole point.