# Contention error in Datastore with Pessimistic concurrency

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I'm using Firestore in Datastore mode in Google Cloud with the Node.js client library. In the Datastore, I have a counter field on an entity that is sometimes needed to be incremented 15-20 times in a few seconds (otherwise it's not written very often). I increment it in a transaction, so that I can read its value before incrementing it. I've read into transaction concurrency modes and checked that

> Firestore in Datastore mode databases use the pessimistic concurrency mode by default.

(I've also set it using the `gcloud` CLI just to make sure)

In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#isolation_and_consistency), under the Pessimistic concurrency mode, it says:

> When two or more concurrent read-write transactions read or write the same data, the lock held by one transaction can delay the other transactions.

So according to my understanding, this mode should wait for the previous transaction to finish before starting the next one and not throw an error (exactly the behavior I want). However, when the counter field is incremented quickly, I still get the error:

> 10 ABORTED: Aborted due to cross-transaction contention. This occurs when multiple transactions attempt to access the same data, requiring Firestore to abort at least one in order to enforce serializability.

I've found some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339969/error-10-aborted-too-much-contention-on-these-documents-please-try-again) here about solutions to this error (like manually delaying the writes), but I'm not sure if I should use these workarounds instead of relying on the database. Do I misunderstand what the pessimistic concurrency is for, or does my client library somehow change this behavior (I could not find any such setting for it)?

I also looked into the [Datastore limits](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits), but they also don't seem to mention anything (other than the legacy Datastore limits) about writing one entity.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There are reasons for the error even with pessimistic concurrency. If multiple transactions try to access the same data together, they can still clash. This happens when transactions start from different sources or are executed rapidly.

Another point is the data size. If the dataset is big, the database might take longer to set locks, causing more conflicts.

To resolve this issue, consider the following approaches I found on this the documentation [Firestore Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/troubleshooting#error_codes):

> - For rapid traffic increases, Firestore attempts to automatically scale to meet the increased demand. When Firestore scales, latency begins to decrease.
> - Hot-spots limit the ability of Firestore to scale up, review designing for scale to identify hot-spots.
> - Review data contention in transactions and your usage of transactions.
> - Reduce the write rate to individual documents.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no way to set it up, so that it waits for longer for the previous transaction to finish (in my case that would be a few seconds only)?